# Good Libraries or Software for Temporal Bayesian Network Structure Learning?

Tags: dataset, time-series, bayesian-networks, model-selection

I would like to infer structures of BNs with edges within and between time slices by using data. I tried libpgm (http://pythonhosted.org/libpgm/) and found that 2TBN is ideal for my purpose, but libpgm does not support structure learning of 2TBN. BNFinder and ebdbNet cannot learn edges within time slices. Could you tell me any great libraries and/or software with which I can infer structures of 2TBN from data or something similar?

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! You can consult [this report](http://www.cim.mcgill.ca/%7Eanqixu/pub/2TBN.TRCIM1030.pdf), and use [the accompanying code](https://github.com/anqixu/2tbn). There is enough (pseudo-)code floating around that you should be able to help yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also read the paper, but what I need is structure learning, which is not mentioned by it, I guess.